# Mysql database scheme

Tags: php, mysql, schema

my friends I have got one Project but also have got some problems,have got so much data fort his reason I can not create database ;

Project : 12 languages and 155.000 data and every product have got 4 differenet package for (example basic, pro, plus, plus pro)

the structure I've done so far is as follows:

2 tables for packages

Package and package_translate

I also have two tables for the products

product and product_translate

here is where I inserted the product translate table now, while adding the product table 12 to the product table will add 1 piece of data and all of these products will be 4 packages, but some of the packages appear in some languages, some of them do not appear, this 4 package products and languages to my mind how to provide the relationship

1) Add 1 column to the package translate table and add 12 languages x 4 packages for a product, which means 48 rows for a product, which means 7 million data in a table

2) package translate add only 12 languages and create the product id, product_langid and package columns in the new table to keep the package, language and product relationship in this table

If you are think I can help you , please write us.

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.0.17+ version which supports *"Creating multi-valued Indexes"* with `CAST(... AS ... ARRAY)` you could consider using JSON for the translations and index it more or less with `INDEX ..( (CAST(<json path> AS VARCHAR(255) ARRAY)) )` ..

Comment: .. if you worry about millions off records, it should be fine for MySQL to handle if the schema, indexes and queries are designed correctly, configuration also helps alot then MySQL can perform just fine into the millions or or even billions off records..